# limit_choices_to within Django model

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, limit-choices-to

I have a project model.  This project contains persons (those who are working on the project).  I am trying to also make a model for each project person, including any notes they have on the project and % complete on project.

My issue is that I want to filter the `individual_person_in_project` to only the persons within the corresponding project.  I am trying to use

```
limit_choices_to = {'person_in_project':User}
```

I want to limit my choices to users who are persons in my `Project` model.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120,null = False,blank = False)
    project_percent_complete = models.IntegerField(blank = True,null = True, default = 0)
    person_in_project = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name = 'project_person',blank = True)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length = 300,null = True,blank = True)

class Project_Person(models.Model):
    corresponding_project = models.ForeignKey(Project,related_name = 'corresponding_project_this_user_is_in',null = False)
    individual_person_in_project = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'a_person_within_the_corresponding_project', limit_choices_to = {'person_in_project':User})
    percent_complete = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Comment: Are you creating objects with a form?

Comment: I not not doing anything within a form.

Comment: It seems like your design might be better to drop the `Project` model's person_in_project field, and let the existence of the `Project_Person` objects, which link a person to a project, be the record of a person in a project. For one, your data would be more normalized, and perhaps even more appealing, the above problem goes away, because the `ProjectPerson` doesn't have to keep track of `person_in_project`.

Comment: Also, as a quick aside, the standard convention for classes in Python, and thus model classes in Django, is not to use underscores, but just CamelCase--so `Project_Person` would be `ProjectPerson`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left a comment above, but I think this is a better answer, anyhow:

You can use [the through option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to track extra information on the manytomanyfield, so you get:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    person_in_project = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='project_person', blank=True, through=ProjectPerson)
```

The docs explain the rest of the details, but you shouldn't have to handle the limit_choices_to in that case.

Comment: This is very good.  The through with the ManyToMany Field lets you add more details to their relationship.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, it was very useful .  The most helpful comment was ryanmrubin and the use of through with ManyToManyField to facilitate their relationship  I ended up creating a separate class and associating that with a project.

If I need to tie more information into this new class I will certainly use through with the ManyToManyField.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120,null = False,blank = False)
    project_percent_complete = models.IntegerField(blank = True,null = True, default = 0)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length = 300,null = True,blank = True)
    people_in_project = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank = True)

class Project_Tasks(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 120,blank = True)
    percent_complete = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique = True,blank = True, null = True)
    project = models.OneToOneField(Project,unique = True, blank = False, null = True)
```